# resetting canvas strokes each re-iteration through the function(animation). how?

Tags: javascript, canvas

At the moment the lines stick permanently creating a drawing. I want the line to be drawm and reset everytime the function is called via setInterval() therefore creating a brain-wave ripple like animation.

Here's my current source code:

```
var rippleEffect = function(){

var co = []; 

for(var i=0; i<=5; i++){
var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*250); 

co.push(r); 
//each time through the loop throws/pushes 6 random numbers to array 'co' for bezier curve.
}

  var canvas = document.getElementById('brainWave');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(500, 75);
  context.bezierCurveTo(co[0], co[1], co[2], co[3], co[4], co[5]);


  context.lineWidth = 2;

  // line color
  context.strokeStyle = '#444';

  context.stroke(); //exicute the stroke based on the structions we've provided. 




};

setInterval(ripple,100); //this re-calls the functions every few miller-seconds.
```

is .clearRect() some part of the solution?

Comment: So isn't there a massive bug with your code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but here are some observations on your code:

- clearRect is essential if you don't want the drawings to accumulate on top of each other.
- setInterval is calling "ripple", but it should be calling "rippleEffect".
- var canvas and var context should be pulled outside-before rippleEffect (they just need to be created once, not with every loop.
- Totally random control points for a Bezier curve yields spaghetti, not brain-waves.

Good luck with your project :)

Comment: sorry when i typed in the source code, i tweaked the ripple name to be more explanatory, ty for your responce i'll see what i can do with your info and shall report back!

Comment: Oki, after another whole day of experimenting & tweaking the code i figured it out. I needed to create a seperate function that's at odds with the main function whichs clear the lines every few millersecs. This creates the desired infinate line zig zag animation.